# REGULAR EXPRESSION Required to unmatch

Tags: regex

```
var str = "##18-Dec-14 5:14 PM IST - admin ##&#xa;Adding Notes from REST :CHETAN##18-Dec-14 5:14 PM IST - admin ##&#xa;Adding Notes from REST :SHRUJAN";
```

Hi I need a regular expression to split the above string based on "##"

But i dont want to match "##&#xa"

Please help

Comment: what tool/language are you using and what is your regex/effort?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative look ahead as

```
/##(?!&#xa)/
```

- `(?!&#xa)` Negative look ahead. Asserts that the `##` is not followed by `&#xa`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gK2fL7/3)